# Class Action Lawsuit data

Tags: data-request, government

Is there a government database of class action lawsuit settlements with open claims?

If not, where do sites like Top class actions get their info?

Comment: Do you mean class action lawsuits against or by the government, or all class action lawsuits? For class action suits where the government isn't involved, I think the only records would be in the courts hearing those cases.